# Time manipulations

Tags: excel, time

Hello I have to count how many people were scheduled on each hour in excel so I transformed starting and ending data/time to only contain time and basing on it I tried to substract these two information but I only get an hour then but what I need is the hours to be like this:

instead
starting on 9:00
ending on 17:00

this
9:00
10:00
11:00
12:00
13:00
14:00
15:00
16:00
17:00

to count every hour that employee was at work. But I don't know how :(
Or is there a better way of doing that?

Comment: If you **subtract** the values you should get what you need. There's no need to **count** them.

Comment: but information that agent worked 8 hours gives me nothing i need to know when the agent was available

Comment: And that bit of information is certainly not clearly articulated in the question. You should read [ask] and try to improve the question.

Comment: Maybe you could ask "I have the following table with start and end times of each person... <show the table> ... and I'm trying to determine how many people were present from 9:00 am to 10: am for example."

Comment: The question is unclear on many levels. What is the input? What does is look like? What are you expecting it to look like after this calculation?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your table looks something like this:

| Person | Start | End | 09:00 | 10:00 | 11:00 | 12:00 | 13:00 | 14:00 | 15:00 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alice | 08:35 | 16:35 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| Bob | 09:35 | 17:35 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| Carl | 10:35 | 18:35 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| Dan | 11:35 | 19:35 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| Ed | 12:35 | 20:35 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Total present |  |  | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 5 | 5 |

You can compute the entries 0 or 1 in each cell under the times using the formula

```
=IF(AND((E$4>$C6);(E$4<=$D6));1;0)
```

In the formula, E$4 is a reference to the column header, e.g. "9:00", $C6 and $D6 are references to the start and end times of the person. They are defined using partial absolute references ($) so the same formula can be copied and pasted in all the cells.

The result will be 1 if the person was present at that time and 0 if not.

The "Total present" formulas just sum up the 1's and 0's in the column.

Comment: Thank you very much, works perfectly :D